# Input field and gldatepicker showing gap

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using gldatepicker its working when use separately but showing a huge gap between the input field and the calender.

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="calender">
    <form method="post" action="test.php" id="frm">
        <input type="text" name="job_date"  id="mydate" /> 
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is my css :

```
#calender {
    width:200px;
    height:190px;
    margin-top:10px;
    float:right;
    background-color:#333;
    position:relative;
}
#mydate {
    float:left;
    width:196px;
}
```

Any idea what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Problem is solved its not the issue of css its the issue within the js file.

Comment: What was the issue? Could you add what you did to fix it?

Comment: Please tell us what is the issue in js. It will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

Use `margin:0` and `padding:0`

```
 #mydate
 {
    float:left;
    width:196px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
 }
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yDcEq/1/)